# when change admobUnitId ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110 it doesn't work?

Tags: android, admob

```
com.clockbyte.admobadapter.sampleapp W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
com.clockbyte.admobadapter.sampleapp W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: Was there a reason for changing it?

Comment: @DanielK yes, because i want to add my unitid